# Soy nuevo en Docker estoy teniendo problemas para crear una imagen a partir de un Dockerfile

Tags: docker

Este es el error que me sale en Docker

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>vim Dockerfile                                                                                      
C:\WINDOWS\system32>docker build -t curso:ubuntu .
[+] Building 0.2s (2/2) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                               0.2s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 2B                                                                                 0.2s
 => CANCELED [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                         0.2s
 => => transferring context:                                                                                       0.2s
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount804542053/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
```

Esta la imagen de mi error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te toca [edit] la pregunta y poner el dockerfile en ella. Posiblemente estás intentando asociar un volumen con un directorio que sólo va a existir en un host Linux...

Comment: Deberías [edit] tu pregunta e incluir el Dockerfile para que podamos ayudarte. Puedes pasarte por las secciones [ask] y [tour] para comprender el funcionamiento de la comunidad.